# Two-way updating GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am trying to implement a GridView with a set amount of data, e.g. if the user scrolls to the bottom, first X items are removed from the data collection and 10 other are added. Similarly, when the top is reached and there are some previous items available, 10 last from the data collection are removed and 10 are added to the front.

I have implemented the data side of the problem, but now I am having problems with the GridView itself - it responds to data set changes by simple replacing the visible items with the new ones, which leads to weird jumps and user-experience inconsistency.

Any tips how to solve the problem so that the user-experience is as close to endless scrolling in both directions as possible?

Comment: Proper implementation of the adapter for your gridView will do this for you.
If you are using ViewHolders all things that you are trying to achieve will be done for you by the properly implemented adapter.

Comment: Are you re-querying the data at the top and bottom? If the data in the query is static and you are simply hiding the part of the data, you don't want to show, then the concept you are trying should work

Comment: @NikolaMilutinovic - The adapter is implemented right, with ViewHolders and all. The problem is that when I update the data collection, the adapter "remaps" the new elements to the old ones, resulting in jumps and re-loads :-(

Comment: @userDEV - Yeah, I am re-querying, the reason for this is the memory preservation, as the grid can in many cases reach thousands of elements quickly, some with images.

Comment: Have you tried using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int)

Comment: @Kelevandos - can you query as top 10, the then next top 20  where rownum > 10, etc.  That way the re-query will reproduce the same recordset

Comment: @NikolaMilutinovic - Wow, that sounds exactly like the behaviour I need! I thought about implementing it with a RecyclerView (and writing my own manager if needed), but I would be really glad if this could be achieved with an "old" GridView. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @userDEV - this does work upwards, but I want to "cut" the data set after a set amount of "pages", reducing the size. If I then return to the beginning of the GridView and requery the previous data, it will (visually) replace the already visible records, resulting in a nasty jump and poor user experience :-(

Comment: Did you get a chance to check this out: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews

Comment: Not this exact page, but I implemented the Endless Scrolling concept just fine. The problem is, it works only one-way and only with the condition that you keep all the data received and just expand it. I need different behaviour :-(